# Different base64 encoding between python versions

Tags: python-2.7, utf-8, base64, python-3.5

I'm having trouble sending an html code through JSON.

I'm noticing my string values are different between python versions (2.7 and 3.5)

My string being something like: `<html><p>PAÇOCA</p></html>`

on **Python 2.7**:

```
x = '<html><p>PAÇOCA</p></html>'
base64.b64encode(x)
=> PGh0bWw+PHA+UEGAT0NBPC9wPjwvaHRtbD4=
```

on **Python 3.5**:

```
x = '<html><p>PAÇOCA</p></html>'
base64.b64encode(x)
=> b'PGh0bWw+PHA+UEHDh09DQTwvcD48L2h0bWw+'
```

Why are these values different?
How can I make the **3.5** string equal to the **2.7**?

This is causing me troubles with receiving e-mails due to the accents being lost.

Comment: `PGh0bWw+PHA+UEGAT0NBPC9wPjwvaHRtbD4=` is the [ cp437,
cp850,
cp852,
cp857,
cp858,
cp860,
cp861,
cp863 or
cp865
] + base64 encoding of `<html><p>PAÇOCA</p></html>`

Comment: `PGh0bWw+PHA+UEHDh09DQTwvcD48L2h0bWw+` is the UTF-8 + base64 encoding of `<html><p>PAÇOCA</p></html>`.

Comment: (I can't help further since I don't know how Python handle character encodings.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example `x` values are not valid Python so it is difficult to tell where the code went wrong, but the answer is to use Unicode strings and explicitly encode them to get consistent answers.  The below code gives the same answer in Python 2 and 3, although Python 3 decorates byte strings with `b''` when printed.  Save the source file in the encoding declared via `#coding`.  The source code encoding can be any encoding that supports the characters used in the source file.  Typically UTF-8 is used for non-ASCII source code, but I made it deliberately different to show it doesn't matter.

```
#coding:cp1252
from __future__ import print_function
import base64
x = u'<html><p>PAÇOCA</p></html>'.encode('utf8')
enc = base64.b64encode(x)
print(enc)
```

Output using Pylauncher to choose the major Python version:

> ```
> C:\>py -2 test.py
> PGh0bWw+PHA+UEHDh09DQTwvcD48L2h0bWw+
>
> C:\>py -3 test.py
> b'PGh0bWw+PHA+UEHDh09DQTwvcD48L2h0bWw+'
> ```

Comment: I think this answer is partially correct.

There might be some cases where the base64 encoding used in python2 is saved in the database. In that case we need a way to get the same base64 encoding as python3.

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: @FareesHussain They are the same. Python 3 just *displays* byte strings with `b''` as an indicator that it is a byte string, but the results in both Python versions are byte strings.

Comment: What I mean is to get the `PGh0bWw+PHA+UEGAT0NBPC9wPjwvaHRtbD4=` base64 encoded value using python3

Comment: @FareesHussain `.decode()` will convert it to a Unicode string, which will print without the bytes notation on Python 3.